# Fetching file into an application which is downloaded from any app in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am facing one problem while fetching a file which is downloaded from an other app into my app.
Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt you could actually access other's application data (downloaded from the internet) **without a jailbroken device**:

> For security reasons, iOS places each app (including its preferences
>   and data) in a sandbox at install time. A sandbox is a set of
>   fine-grained controls that limit the app’s access to files,
>   preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on. As part of the
>   sandboxing process, the system installs each app in its own sandbox
>   directory, which acts as the home for the app and its data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot access file of other application.But in iOS 5 there is new feature called iCloud, I think you can use this.